# Python Glob - Get Full Filenames, but no directory-only names

Tags: python-3.x, glob

This code works, but it's returning directory names and filenames. I haven't found a parameter that tells it to return only files or only directories.
Can glob.glob do this, or do I have to call os.something to test if I have a directory or file.  In my case, my files all end with .csv, but I would like to know for more general knowledge as well.

In the loop, I'm reading each file, so currently bombing when it tries to open a directory name as a filename.

```
files = sorted(glob.glob(input_watch_directory + "/**", recursive=True))
for loop_full_filename in files:
    print(loop_full_filename)
```

Results:

```
c:\Demo\WatchDir\
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\01
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\01\polygonData_2022_07_01__15_51.csv
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\01\polygonData_2022_07_01__15_52.csv
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\01\polygonData_2022_07_01__15_53.csv
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\01\polygonData_2022_07_01__15_54.csv
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\01\polygonData_2022_07_01__15_55.csv
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\05
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\05\polygonData_2022_07_05__12_00.csv
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\05\polygonData_2022_07_05__12_01.csv
```

Results needed:

```
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\01\polygonData_2022_07_01__15_51.csv
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\01\polygonData_2022_07_01__15_52.csv
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\01\polygonData_2022_07_01__15_53.csv
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\01\polygonData_2022_07_01__15_54.csv
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\01\polygonData_2022_07_01__15_55.csv
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\05\polygonData_2022_07_05__12_00.csv
c:\Demo\WatchDir\2202\07\05\polygonData_2022_07_05__12_01.csv
```

For this specific program, I can just check if the file name contains.csv, but I would like to know in general for future reference.

Comment: Unsure about `glob.glob`, but I know `Pathlib.PurePath.name` will allow you to easily return only the filename and file extension when iterating through directories. Docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name

Answer (score 1):

Line:

```
files = sorted(glob.glob(input_watch_directory + "/**", recursive=True))
```

replace with the line:

```
files = sorted(glob.glob(input_watch_directory + "/**/*.*", recursive=True))
```